# Como pegar o IP do cliente em PHP?

Tags: php

Já pesquisei em vários fóruns e inclusive aqui porém nenhuma das soluções que vi me trouxeram o resultado correto.
Em todas as tentativas recebo como ip **::1**

Segue código que estou utilizando

```
<?php

  if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   
    {
      $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
  elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))  
    {
      $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
  else
    {
      $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
  echo $ip_address;
?>
```

Comment: @Stormwind Não possuí solução

Comment: @RORSCHACH, não possui solução aceita, mas se você vê a primeira resposta, ela já responde isso que o usuário quer (mais especificamente na 3ª linha).

Answer (score 0):

Tente este código:

```
<?PHP

function getUserIP()
{
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $client;
    }
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $forward;
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $remote;
    }

    return $ip;
}


$user_ip = getUserIP();

echo $user_ip; // Output IP address [Ex: 177.87.193.134]


?>
```

Não esqueça de **não** acessar a sua página pelo link `https://localhost` , ao invés disso, acesse pelo link `www.nomedoseusite.com` se estiver hospedado ou pelo seu ***IP***:

```
https://192.168.0.1 //Seu número de IP
```